# How to fix 416 <Get Error in scrapy python

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Hi everyone I want to **scrape** all the names but when I run my code I'm getting this error:

```
2019-08-25 23:08:10 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (416) <GET https://www.manta.com/distil_r_blocked.html?requestId=e243a58b-d46d-4d12-

HTTP status code is not handled or n
ot allowed
```

Code:

```
import scrapy

class project(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'project'
    start_urls = ['https://www.manta.com/mb_43_A0_02/advertising_and_marketing/alaska']

    def parse(self, response):
        seller_name = response.css('.h4 strong::text').extract()
        yield {'seller name': seller_name}
```

Comment: The site has gdpr check (don't know if that applies to you). If you have a set-up which blocks cookie setting then this may be part of it.

Comment: Manta uses Distil as a CDN, they have some anti-DDOS protection that you're not going to  get around with scrapy.

Comment: @pguardiario so what can i do know?

Comment: @QHarr What can i do know?

Comment: I think some of the captcha solvers (2captcha) are selling distil sessions now, that's your best bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, scrapy work only with successful responses - if status codes are in the 200-300 range
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#module-scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror

For work with 416 response use

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [416]
```

And then you can work with this response

```
if response.status == 416:
    # write code what you need
```

In your case website protect with distilnetworks and usually such websites not like if scrape them.
I think you need to read rules on this website about scraping, they to allow or not allow it.
Of course, exist different service for bypass (people wrote you in comment) protect but need remember about morality and law.

Comment: Anyway, you need to add `handle_httpstatus_list = [416]` in your project

Comment: `if response.status == 416:` - and then write code wht you need.

Comment: can you mention in the answer so it's easier to understand for me!

Comment: Are you wrote protection bypass? `# write code what you need` - instead of this?

Comment: in if condition I want to scrap